# How to use json string value to get iota value?

Tags: string, go, iota

I have a constutil package where I have defined some const values using iota.

```
package constutil

type UserType uint

const (
    Free UserType = iota + 1
    Premium UserType
    ...
)
```

From `json` I will get `{"user": "Premium", ...}`. Now I need to save the value of the user like for `Premium` it's `2`. I tried to get the value like this:

```
constutil.(req.User)
```

But it didn't work as `req.User` returns a `string` like: `"Premium"`.

I can just do it using `map[string]uint`. But is there any way of doing it using `iota`?

Comment: Not a good idea what you are trying. You should save "Premium" and not 2. Why? Because if you safe 2 and you add a constant to your package maybe 2 will be the value for Free.

Comment: @apxp In `user definition table` the `ID` of  `Premium` user is 2 and I need to save the ID not the value.

Answer (score 2):

Its best to use const string for such Enum use case.

```
type UserType string

const(
  Premium UserType = "Premium"
)
```

OR else define custom marshal/unmasrshal:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type UserType uint

func (u UserType) String() string{
    return "Premium"
}

const(
  Premium UserType = 1
)

type User struct{
    T UserType `json:"type"`
}

func (u *User) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(&struct {
        T string
    }{
        T:    fmt.Sprint(u.T),
    })
}

func (u *User) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    aux := &struct {
        T string `json:"type"`
    }{  }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &aux); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println(aux.T)
    switch aux.T{
    case "Premium":
        u.T = Premium
    }
    return nil
}


func main() {
    b := []byte(`{"type":"Premium"}`)
    x := new(User)
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, x); err != nil{
        fmt.Printf("err: %v\n", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("unmasrshalled: %v\n", *x)
    fmt.Printf("type: %d\n", x.T)
    b, _ = json.Marshal(x)
    fmt.Printf("marshalled: %v\n", string(b))

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't think there is any built-in way of mapping between `iota` values and strings. There are some tools that generate code for doing the mapping.

I've been in similar situations and i've done something like this when I didn't want to depend on generators or other tools. Hope it serves as a start for something.

https://play.golang.org/p/MxPL-0FVGMt

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type UserType uint

const (
    UserTypeFree UserType = iota
    UserTypePremium
)

var UserTypeToString = map[UserType]string{
    UserTypeFree:    "Free",
    UserTypePremium: "Premium",
}

var UserTypeFromString = map[string]UserType{
    "Free":    UserTypeFree,
    "Premium": UserTypePremium,
}

func (ut UserType) String() string {
    if s, ok := UserTypeToString[ut]; ok {
        return s
    }
    return "unknown"
}

func (ut UserType) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if s, ok := UserTypeToString[ut]; ok {
        return json.Marshal(s)
    }
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("unknown user type %d", ut)
}

func (ut *UserType) UnmarshalJSON(text []byte) error {
    var s string
    if err := json.Unmarshal(text, &s); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    var v UserType
    var ok bool
    if v, ok = UserTypeFromString[s]; !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("unknown user type %s", s)
    }
    *ut = v
    return nil
}

func main() {
    var ut UserType

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(`"Free"`), &ut)

    fmt.Printf("%#v %v \n", ut, ut)

    b, _ := json.Marshal(ut)

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", string(b))

}
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using two maps `UserType -> string` and `string -> UserType`. Rather implement only one and have a `for` loop that extracts key from value. You reduce possible inconsistencies.

Comment: Yes good point. If there is lots of types i would probably generate in some way. Another solution if there is not hundreds of mappings for a type is to use just one map and iterate when mapping in one of the directions instead. My guess is that it will not be your performance bottleneck.